# Can Davinci Resolve convert a movie into (png) pictures...?

Tags: video, conversion, davinci-resolve

I'm a new user of **Davinci Resolve**. I would like to know if I can use it for converting a video into its pictures ? Do you have a tutorial that explains to me how is the workflow ? maybe on Youtube ? very thanks.

Comment: With a simple search on a very popular search engine I found the answer on the BlackMagic Davinci Resolve forum.

Comment: man,I haven't asked which kind of graphic files da vinci supports,but what's the workflow if I want to convert a video into its pictures...

Comment: We will need a lot kore information on your workflow. System setup  current apps etc.

Comment: use Apple compressor (assuming your using an Apple Mac to convert from video file to png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Blackmagic Forum "You can only export TIFF files (which then can be converted to png's with an external tool), not PNG's directly. "